# Помогите сделать правильный запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть база, в ней есть поле, под именем group. Выполняю запрос вида:

```sql
SELECT nick FROM имя базы WHERE group=1234;
```

Получаю:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group=1234' at line 1

Если вместо поля group использовать другие поля - всё норм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закавычьте group: `group`` - это зарезервированное слово (без третьей кавычки - она Хешкоду нужна =) ).
И вообще, берите привычку кавычить все: и названия столбцов, и названия таблиц. А значения типа "строка" брать в одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Собственно, я пробовал брать в кавычки, не помогло, а вот в обратные кавычки взять не догадался). С обратными действительно работает! Спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("SELECT `nick` FROM `table` WHERE `group`='1234'");
```